# What does "in shares" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> He has sunk his capital in shares in the company.

What does this sentence mean? Has he sunk his capital by buying the company's shares?

Comment: Maybe, ironically, in the sense it's not a very liquid investment vehicle(or is it?); another comment alludes to that in the context of a loss.

Answer (score 2):

More than the *speed* at which he invested his money in the company, I think the verb *sink* indicates that the investment can be seen as probably unrecoverable.

Sometimes things *do* sink slowly, but many things that are *sunk* are lost forever.

The idea is that he has invested his money in a company, and he may cannot pull that money out (easily) at this moment.

Comment: *Not recoverable now* is not *an unrecoverable loss*. Money invested in a long-term project may well produce a handsome dividend; but it is still sunk.

Answer (score 1):

Shares are investments in companies, so to say:

```
He has sunk his capital in shares in the company.
```

Means:

```
He has all of his capital invested in companies
```

Sunk indicates that he likely did it quickly, sinking is usually not a slow process.

Answer (score 0):

**Sunk Capital** is capital (money) that is used for one thing and cannot be recovered.

[This blog](http://kalyan-city.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/what-is-capital-meaning-features-and.html?m=1) has a good explanation

> **Sunk capital** : Capital goods which have only a specific use in producing a particular commodity are called Sunk capital. E.g. A textile weaving machine can be used only in textile mill. It cannot be used elsewhere. It is sunk capital.

In the context of the quote "he" has used all his money to buy the shares. Quite possibly the shares are now trading for less than he bought them at, so he is depending on the value rising or the company to pay dividends in order to get his money back.

Comment: Yes, but this is not sunk capital. It is to sink your capital into something. It's the same as: has all his capital tied up in the company. Whether or not he can retrieve it would depend on whether or not it is a public company.

Answer (score 0):

"He has sunk his capital in shares in the company".
means:

He has put all his money into shares of the company. Shares means: a portion of the company where ownership is given by shares. This can be stocks in the company for a publicly listed company or a percentage of the company if private. If you sink all your money into something, it means you have  no more money in the bank. You have spent it all.

[sink something into something. **an idiomatic expression in English**, Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/sink_something_into)

**Put money or energy into (something); invest something in.
‘many investors sank their life savings into the company’**